# pNorm result of ''survMisc" package in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I tried the same method in this link:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/problems-when-applying-function-comp/16818
but the result of pNorm is just the rank:

```
                Q        Var       Z       pNorm
1            10.25050    6.34099 4.0707     6
n           271.00000 5462.61156 3.6666     4
sqrtN        51.16275  173.75714 3.8813     1
S1            6.36221    2.87942 3.7493     2
S2            6.12261    2.69899 3.7268     3
FH_p=1_q=1    1.66465    0.22122 3.5393     5
                   maxAbsZ        Var      Q pSupBr
1            10.25050    6.34099 4.0707      6
n           271.00000 5462.61156 3.6666      4
sqrtN        51.16275  173.75714 3.8813      1
S1            6.36221    2.87942 3.7493      2
S2            6.12261    2.69899 3.7268      3
FH_p=1_q=1    1.66465    0.22122 3.5393      5
NULL
```

I don't know how to display the result in exact p-value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In github, I found the functions required to convert Z and Q into p-values in comp function (see https://github.com/cran/survMisc/blob/master/R/comp.R).

Especially, `pNorm=2 * (1 - stats::pnorm(abs(Z)))`

and `pSupBr = probSupBr(Q)` where

```
probSupBr <- function(x) {
    k <- c(0L, seq.int(1e4))
    1 - (4 / pi) * (sum(((( - 1)^k) / (2 * k + 1)) * exp(-(((pi^2) * (2 * k + 1)^2) / (8 * x^2)))))
}
```

Enjoy !